# Libusb compatibility with Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, libusb

Does anyone have any information regarding compatibility of libusb with Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not going to work as there is no way to access the required USB APIs on the platform, let alone make them available in a cross-platform way.

Comment: Ok, I'll take your word for it!